# Weird " (double quotes) appearing in whitespace between digits and % (percentage) symbol

Tags: html, css, webfonts

So I have this in my HTML:

[image]

But I see this in my page:

[image]

We use a webfont called Graphik, legally purchased from their website and we use woff and woff2. I tested their site and it doesn't happen.

It only happens with a font-weight of 300. Our settings in general are incredibly standard, and I have utf-8 added on the head.

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Don't you think the issue is supposed to be raised to them instead ?

Comment: Considering it works fine on their site I'm not sure. They don't provide code support.